# Is this possible in sql? moodle

Tags: sql, moodle

Hi i am doing a project in Moodle and have got a question if this is even possible. I have got this 3 queries that i am trying to put into one.

```
    select c.fullname, count(1) as total from {role_assignments} ra INNER JOIN 
    {logstore_standard_log}  as lsl ON ra.userid = lsl.userid  
    INNER JOIN {course} as c on lsl.courseid =c.id 
    WHERE  lsl.action="viewed" and lsl.target = "course" GROUP BY c.fullname



       select c.fullname, count(1) as student from {role_assignments} ra INNER JOIN 
       {logstore_standard_log}  as lsl ON ra.userid = lsl.userid  
       INNER JOIN {course} as c on lsl.courseid =c.id 
       WHERE ra.roleid=5 AND lsl.action="viewed" and lsl.target = "course" GROUP BY c.fullname


   select c.fullname, count(1) as rest from {role_assignments} ra INNER JOIN 
   {logstore_standard_log}  as lsl ON ra.userid = lsl.userid  
   INNER JOIN {course} as c on lsl.courseid =c.id 
   WHERE ra.roleid!=5 AND lsl.action="viewed" and lsl.target = "course" GROUP BY c.fullname
```

From what i have seen this could probably be done with subqueries but i cant seem to find a way to do it.

[image: Desired result]

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with one query.

```
SELECT lsl.courseid, c.fullname,
     COUNT(*) as total,
     SUM(CASE WHEN ra.roleid = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as student,
     SUM(CASE WHEN ra.roleid <> 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as rest
FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log as lsl
JOIN mdl_role_assignments ra ON ra.userid = lsl.userid  
JOIN mdl_course AS c ON c.id = lsl.courseid
WHERE lsl.action = 'viewed' AND lsl.target = 'course'
GROUP BY lsl.courseid, c.fullname
```

Although, a user can have more than one role in a course, so the `total` and `rest` columns will be distorted.

You should also group by the courseid because there could be duplicate course names.

Answer (score 0):

If all your queries has same output format then you can use `UNION`

```
select c.fullname, count(1) as total, NULL as student, null as rest from {role_assignments} ra INNER JOIN 
{logstore_standard_log}  as lsl ON ra.userid = lsl.userid  
INNER JOIN {course} as c on lsl.courseid =c.id 
WHERE  lsl.action="viewed" and lsl.target = "course" GROUP BY c.fullname

UNION

select c.fullname, null, count(1) as student, null from {role_assignments} ra INNER JOIN 
{logstore_standard_log}  as lsl ON ra.userid = lsl.userid  
INNER JOIN {course} as c on lsl.courseid =c.id 
WHERE ra.roleid=5 AND lsl.action="viewed" and lsl.target = "course" GROUP BY 
  c.fullname

UNION

select c.fullname, null, null, count(1) as rest from {role_assignments} ra INNER JOIN 
{logstore_standard_log}  as lsl ON ra.userid = lsl.userid  
INNER JOIN {course} as c on lsl.courseid =c.id 
WHERE ra.roleid!=5 AND lsl.action="viewed" and lsl.target = "course" GROUP BY    
 c.fullname
```

**PS: pay attention to `select` part**